# Cannot access current_user in controller (Devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

The question is simple but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

I have a controller that require I have access to the current login user in Devise. But when I try to access `current_user` from controller the result is `nil`

However access it in the Model and View works just fine.

I've tried to put

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

On either Application controller or my controller but it doesn't work

What should I do to make this work as expected?

Comment: Is the user logged in? You can check with `user_signed_in?`

Comment: Yes, the Cancan works fine. In the template shows up the email of the user

Comment: first of all current_user is inaccessible from model. second: show us the code where u trying to access this var in the controller, or no one will be able to help you